# using case_when directly on a factor

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

I can't figure something straightforward to do this simple thing :

I have a variable `age_cl` which is a factor object with age as classes.

If I want to merge two levels I'll just go easily with a `forcats::fct_collapse`.

However, now I would like to split one level in two different levels (e.g. the "25-34" level into a "25-29" and a "30-34" using the initial integer `age` variable to conditionally split).

I couldn't find any equivalent in forcats to do so, hence I'd like to use a standard `case_when` but it only takes character vector as input...

Anyone with any thoughts on this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide some example data ?

Comment: You would need first convert the `factor` variable (`age_cl`) to `character` - then manipulate it by `case_when` then convert it back to `factor` with updated levels

Comment: yes i did with a character conversion but was wondering if there was a way to work directly on factor vector...thanks for the answers !

Comment: @RonakShah

`df <- data.frame(


  age = c(25:34),  
  age_cl = as.factor(c("25-34","25-34","25-34","25-34","25-34",  
                       "25-34","25-34","25-34","25-34","25-34")),  
  age_cl_expected = as.factor(c("25-29","25-29","25-29","25-29","25-29",  
                                "30-34","30-34","30-34","30-34","30-34"))  
)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `cut` ? You can put custom breaks and labels for it.

```
breaks <- c(24, 29, 34)
labels <- paste(breaks[-length(breaks)] + 1, breaks[-1], sep = '-')
labels
#[1] "25-29" "30-34"

transform(df, age_cl = cut(age, breaks, labels))

#   age age_cl age_cl_expected
#1   25  25-29           25-29
#2   26  25-29           25-29
#3   27  25-29           25-29
#4   28  25-29           25-29
#5   29  25-29           25-29
#6   30  30-34           30-34
#7   31  30-34           30-34
#8   32  30-34           30-34
#9   33  30-34           30-34
#10  34  30-34           30-34
```

Comment: thanks @RonakShah it works very fine. however it doesn't quite address the issue since I was wondering if there was a way to split a level of an already existing factor. This solution enables to recreate the whole factor `age_cl` out of the cut statement which is a nice alternative to a case_when

Comment: Looking only at 25-34 you don't know if the age is 25 or 30 so you can't directly assign 25-30 to either group 25-29 or 30-34 without going back to `age`.

Comment: yes of course using `age` is inevitable. It is just different to split a level of an existing factor or to recreate a whole factor and all its levels. Well that's not the case here nor very likely to happen but imagine you don't have the `age` value for all levels other than  "25-34". In that theoretical case, you will want to keep the levels as they are except for the 25-34 level which you will want to split according to the values of age. This is definitely doable with some trick but it doesn't seem to be possible directly on the factor itself. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and answer !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What I am trying to say is when I say my age is between 25 and 34 you have no idea if you should be put me in bucket 25-29 or 30-34.

Comment: yes that's true and that's why you need the  `age` variable. but nevermind, it seems that this is not possible to do what i wanted without some tricks